# changing the date format to a format r can identify

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'm using this dataset (this is the head of my df) `c("31 Mar 1999", "25 Mar 2019", "27 Nov 1996", "21 Jan 2003","22 Nov 2000", "11 Dec 2011")`

I'm attempting to extract the year from these dates using this code:

`netflix_and_disney$release_year <- as_date(netflix_and_disney$release_year)`

I've tried many other date functions. However, I continue to get the same or similar error message relating to the non unambiguous format: "All formats failed to parse. No formats found."

How would I change the format in order to extract the year from each observation?

Comment: `as.Date(x, format = "%d %b %Y")`

Answer (score -2):

Using `lubridate` :

```
x <- c("31 Mar 1999","25 Mar 2019","27 Nov 1996","21 Jan 2003","22 Nov 2000","11 Dec 2011")
library(lubridate)
year(dmy(x))
#[1] 1999 2019 1996 2003 2000 2011
```

---

In base R, assuming your locale is English

```
format(as.Date(x, "%d %b %Y"), "%Y")
#[1] "1999" "2019" "1996" "2003" "2000" "2011"
```